# Не могу эффективно распараллелить 2 процесса на python

Tags: python, linux, многопоточность, очередь, keras

Здравствуйте! Я пытаюсь распараллелить 2 операции:

1. Процесс обучение нейронной сети на Keras. Использую метод
   model.fit() из этой библиотеки. https://keras.io/models/model/
2. Процесс зачитки данных для обучения этой сети с SSD-диска в
   оперативную память. Все данные занимают 300Gb и в оперативку не
   влезают, у меня её всего 16Gb.

Т.е. хочется, чтобы было так:

a) Переписываются в оперативку 5Gb данных

b) На этих данных сетка начинает обучаться.

c) Одновременно с п. b), пока сетка обучается, с диска в память переписываются ещё 5Gb данных.

d) Как только сетка обучилась на первых данных, она сразу начинает обучаться на уже подготовленных вторых данных. Одновременно с этим запускается процесс переписывания 3х данных. И так далее.

Я это сделал, но работает всё следующим образом. Сначала, на первом шаге (а), всё читается с диска очень здорово. Скорость чтения с диска около 40MB/s. Сразу поясню, у меня данные с диска читаются из большого  файла h5py и выбираются из него строки в случайном порядке, поэтому скорость не 3500MB/s :), т.е. процессор тормозит весь процесс чтения своими вычислениями. Так вот, сначала всё приемлемо быстро, но когда начинает одновременно с этим обучатся сетка, то скорость чтения сразу падает до 13-15MB/s. И, что самое неприятное, сетка начинает обучаться в 1,5 раза медленнее, когда эти операции начинают происходить одновременно. Т.е. два процесса, как бы, борются за ресурс - CPU. Соответственно и GPU, который используется в обучении начинает не догружаться и вместо 85-90% его загрузки, я начинаю наблюдать 50-60%. При этом, общая загрузка CPU не поднимается выше 25-30%. Скрин-шот "Системного монитора" с графиками загрузки CPU приложу ниже.

Вот код. Не весь, правда. Я из него выкинул где-то строчек 200 кода которые относятся только к сетке и к делу не относятся. Самое главное - это модуль data_gen_v2 и метод nn_model.model_fit:

## Основная программа

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./moduls")
import data_gen_v2 as my_gen

class MyModel():
    '''Класс который создает сверточную нейронную ctnm'''
    def __init__(self, files, epoch_size, batch_size, Frame, cand_param, num_target_cat):
        '''Инициируем наши данные'''  
        self.train_file = files[0]
        self.test_file = files[1]
        self.epoch_size = epoch_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.Frame = Frame
        self.cand_param = cand_param
        self.num_target_cat = num_target_cat

    def make_model(self):
        #описание слоёв и пр. В общем, моя сетка
        return nn

    def model_fit(self, nn, mem_stp, file_mod):

        for e in range(self.epoch_size):
            print("Эпоха - {}".format(e+1))
        
            # Обучение
            print("Обучение")
            gen = my_gen.fast_gen(self.train_file, mem_stp)
            #all_hist = []
            for i in gen:
                Data_X = i[0]
                Data_Y = i[1]
                history = nn.fit(Data_X, [Data_Y, Data_Y],
                                 initial_epoch = 0,
                                 epochs = 1,
                                 batch_size = self.batch_size)
                #all_hist.appen(history)
            #nn.save('./{}-{}'.format(file_mod, e+1))
            #all_hist -> json
        
            # Валидация
            print("Валидация")
            gen = my_gen.fast_gen(self.test_file, mem_stp)
            #all_eval = []
            for i in gen:
                Data_X = i[0]
                Data_Y = i[1]
                eval_s = nn.evaluate(Data_X, [Data_Y, Data_Y])
                #all_eval.appen(eval_s)
            #all_eval -> json

#nn - это моя скомпилированная сетка
#mem_stp - это кол-во строк данных, которые должен поместить в память и занять 5Gb
#file_mod - это имя файла, куда сохранять веса сетки.
nn_model = MyModel(files, epoch_size, batch_size, Frame, cand_param, num_target_cat)
nn = nn_model.make_model()
nn_model.model_fit(nn, mem_stp, file_mod)
```

## Импортированный модуль data_gen_v2

```
import random
import math
import threading, queue
import numpy as np
import h5py


def get_data(file_info, ind_s, ind_e, q):

    file = file_info[0]
    len_data = file_info[1]
    Fr_len = file_info[2]
    Data_ALL = file_info[3]
    data_ind_sh = file_info[4]

    if ind_e > len_data:
        ind_e = len_data

    mem_ind = data_ind_sh[ind_s:ind_e]
    len_step = len(mem_ind)
    for i in range(len(Fr_len) - 1):
            Data_ALL[i] = np.zeros((len_step, Fr_len[i][0], Fr_len[i][1]), dtype='float32')
    Data_ALL[-1] = np.zeros((len_step, Fr_len[-1][0]), dtype='float32')

    with h5py.File(file) as f:
        for i in range(len_step):
            Data_ALL[0][i] = f['data_X_0'][mem_ind[i]]
            Data_ALL[1][i] = f['data_X_1'][mem_ind[i]]
            Data_ALL[2][i] = f['data_X_2'][mem_ind[i]]
            Data_ALL[3][i] = f['data_X_3'][mem_ind[i]]
            Data_ALL[4][i] = f['data_X_4'][mem_ind[i]]
            Data_ALL[5][i] = f['data_Y'][mem_ind[i]]

    Data_X = Data_ALL[:5]
    Data_Y = Data_ALL[-1] * -1

    q.put([Data_X, Data_Y])


def fast_gen(file, mem_stp):
    with h5py.File(file) as f:
        data_X_f = f['data_X_0']
        len_data = len(data_X_f)
        Fr_len = []
        for item in f:
            len_fr = f[item][0].shape
            Fr_len.append(len_fr)
    Data_ALL = [i for i in range(len(Fr_len))]
    data_ind_sh = [i for i in range(len_data)]
    random.shuffle(data_ind_sh)

    file_info = [file, len_data, Fr_len, Data_ALL, data_ind_sh]
    ind_s = 0
    ind_e = mem_stp
    q = queue.Queue()
    threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(file_info, ind_s, ind_e, q)).start()

    last_step = int((math.ceil(len_data/mem_stp)-1)*mem_stp)
    for i in range(0, len_data, mem_stp):
        ind_s = i + mem_stp
        ind_e = ind_s + mem_stp
        Data_XY = q.get()
        if i != last_step:
            print("Запустилась get_data. Итерация - {}".format(i))
            threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(file_info, ind_s, ind_e, q)).start()
        yield Data_XY
```

Т.е. видно, что я в генераторе использую threading и queue для распараллеливания. Может быть это не подходящий метод? Можно ли как-то жестко задать, что метод fit() использует, например ядра 1 и 2, а генератор использует ядра 3 и 4? Сделать так, чтобы эти 2 процесса не мешали друг другу. Может быть как-то средствами python или как-то ядро операционки настроить по другому, у меня Ubuntu 16.04. Я знаю, что в ядре можно настроить планировщик и прочие вещи, но не знаю что будет лучше работать в моем случае :) Мне нужно ядро больше латенси или наоборот? Пытался настроить ядро по этой статье (https://habrahabr.ru/post/234653/), думая, что в моем случае режим работы будет похожим, только патчи BFS и BFQ не ставил. Короче, не знаю с какой стороны подходить к моей проблеме. Подскажите пожалуйста, знающие люди, а то я уже себе всю голову сломал :)

## Дописал 5.10.17. Ответ на комментарии @0andriy.

Просто не смог разобраться с синтаксисом форматирования в комментах, поэтому дополнил сообщение(то у меня строка не переводилась, ни 2 пробелами, ни 
, то код было не реально вписывать...).

Итак, я когда зачитываю данные из h5py файла, я их читаю из 6 разных датасетов в этом файле:
Нулевой numpy массив№1, строчка[n] = file['daset_1'][num],
Нулевой numpy массив№2, строчка[n] = file['daset_2'][num]
...
Нулевой numpy массив№6, строчка[n] = file['daset_6'][num],
номер строчки (num) у всех 6 датасетов одинаковый, но каждый раз выбирается случайно. Затем переходим к следующей строчке num, и так до тех пор, пока не зачитаем столько датасетов из file, сколько влезает в оперативку. В итоге получается 6 numpy массивов со случайно выбранными строчками из file, но сохраняется соответствие строчек между массивами №1-№6.
Так вот, я запустил процесс зачитки из файла через
'multiprocessing.Pool'
Делаю это примерно так:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def file_read(args):
    file = args[0]
    mem_ind = args[1]
    name_dset = args[2]
    Data_ALL = args[3]
    args = []
    with h5py.File(file) as f:
        for num, item in enumerate(mem_ind):
            Data_ALL[num] = f[name_dset][item] # В этом месте постоянно всё виснет
        print("Переменная {} из h5py зачитанна".format(name_dset))
    return Data_ALL

def make_pool(args):
    p = Pool(2)
    Data_ALL = p.map(file_read, args)
    p.close()
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    return Data_ALL

#  Создаю пустые numpy массивы, для последующего наполния из file
#  len_step = 32000 - кол-во строчек, которые влезают в оперативку

Data_ALL = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] #  Просто числа, которые потом будут перезаписаны нулевыми numpy массивами.
for i in range(5):
     Data_ALL[i] = np.zeros((len_step, 1000, 4), dtype='float32')
Data_ALL[-1] = np.zeros((len_step, 1), dtype='float32')

#  Описываю нужные датасеты и строчки, которые нужно выбирать
#  mem_ind = [список из случайно выбранных строчек, его длина равна len_step]
arg_0 = [file, mem_ind, 'data_X_0', Data_ALL[0]]
Data_ALL[0] = [] #  Зачищаю нулевой массив, для экономии оперативки
arg_1 = [file, mem_ind, 'data_X_1', Data_ALL[1]]
Data_ALL[1] = []
arg_2 = [file, mem_ind, 'data_X_2', Data_ALL[2]]
Data_ALL[2] = []
arg_3 = [file, mem_ind, 'data_X_3', Data_ALL[3]]
Data_ALL[3] = []
arg_4 = [file, mem_ind, 'data_X_4', Data_ALL[4]]
Data_ALL[4] = []
arg_5 = [file, mem_ind, 'data_Y', Data_ALL[5]]
Data_ALL = []
args = [arg_0, arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, arg_4, arg_5]

#  Запускаю зачитку из файла в 2х параллельных процессах.
Data_ALL = make_pool(args)
```

Сначала всё работает нормально и всё хороше работает, но в случайный момент времени (не понятно от чего это зависит, может случится после 50 итераций и т.д.) всё виснет в этом месте

```
with h5py.File(file) as f:
     for num, item in enumerate(mem_ind):
          Data_ALL[num] = f[name_dset][item] # В этом месте постоянно всё виснет
```

Причем, все датасеты зачитываются: data_X_1, data_X_2, data_X_3, data_X_4, data_Y, кроме data_X_0. И при зачитке data_X_0 всё виснет и больше никуда не двигается, общий большой цикл программы ждет зачитанных данных, а этого не происходит и приходится жать ^+C, чтобы выйти из программы и перезапустить её заново. При этом перезапуск почти никогда не помогает, тогда нужно перезапускать комп :) И перезагрузка это лечит не всегда. В итоге ждешь 2 часа, пока всё работает и сетка нормально обучается, а потом БАХ, и всё надо перезапускать заново :(

Сейчас попробую всё переделать без multiprocessing.Pool, а при помощи mmap(). Может тогда данные будут очень быстро зачитываться и мне не понадобится это распараллеливать.

Comment: *т.е. процессор тормозит весь процесс чтения своими вычислениями.* -- это заявление скорее всего ошибочно. Самая медленная часть в системе -- ввод-вывод.

Comment: Дальше, в python есть проблема по имени GIL -- global interpreter lock, на которую вы тоже натыкаетесь.

Comment: Ну и часть про начало -- это скорее всего заполнение кэшей, потому всё "летает", вам нужно убедиться, что файл вы открываете, используя *mmap()*.

Comment: @0andriy, огромное спасибо, что мне ответили. Я просто только сейчас увидел Ваш комментарий. Когда запостил вопрос, пару дней ждал какого-нибудь ответа, но никто не отвечал, я подумал, что ответа и не будет :) Параллельно сам пытался что-то придумать и придумал-таки, но работает это криво :( Сейчас опишу что именно я сделал и в чем теперь проблема, может быть подскажете как с этим бороться?

Comment: И по поводу mmap - отдельное спасибо, я раньше открывал файл при помощи with h5py.File(file) as f: Сейчас попробую всё переделать через mmap(), может это решит мою проблему.

Comment: Пытался описать, в каком сейчас всё состоянии здесь, в комментах, но ничего у меня не получилось с синтаксисом форматирования, который здесь используется, поэтому сейчас отредактирую своё начальное сообщение и допишу туда описание своей теперяшней ситуации. Минут через 15 будет готово

Comment: mmap() не помог :( Не смог я зачитать свой h5py файл при помощи этой функции. Бьюсь с зависаниями при использовании multiprocessing, но пока не выходит.... Виснет и всё!

Comment: Вроде бы решил проблему :) Оказывается multiprocessing плохо работает при больших объемах данных. Просто уменьшил кол-во строчек, которые я зачитываю за раз и всё стало работать, как надо. Ура!!! :)

Comment: Скорее спрятали. Вот тут свежая статейка про I/O в Linux, позволяет заглянуть под капот: http://www.scylladb.com/2017/10/05/io-access-methods-scylla/

Comment: Спасибо большое! Хоть и так сейчас всё удовлетворительно работает (бОльшая скорость наполнения "буфера" не нужна - имеются более длительные процессы, которые всё равно нужно будет ждать, обучение самой нейронной сетки), но обязательно почитаю, очень интересно. Спасибо!